# Using Cygwin in Windows 8, chmod 600 does not work as expected?

Tags: windows, cygwin, windows-8-preview, chmod

I'm trying to change the permissions to my key file `key.pem` in [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) 1.7.11. It has the permissions flags: `-rw-rw----`

```
chmod -c 600 key.pem
```

Reports:

> mode of 'key.pem' changed from 0660 (rw-rw----) to 0600 (rw-------)

However:

```
ls -l key.pem
```

still reports

> key.pem's permission flags are still: -rw-rw----

This reason why I'm asking is that ssh is complaining:

> Permissions 0660 for 'key.pem' are too open.

when I try to ssh into my Amazon EC2 instance.
**Is this an issue with Cygwin & Windows 8 NTFS or am I missing something?**

Comment: This sounds like a Win8/Cygwin bug. I'd recommend reporting it on the [Cygwin mailing list](http://cygwin.com/lists.html).

Comment: It might be related to NTFS... Windows doesn't really use that Linux scheme. Maybe you can try going into the windows permission settings and only give yourself rights...

Comment: I think this is related to http://superuser.com/questions/363141/using-git-through-cygwin-on-windows-8

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I'm using Cygwin in the Win8CP, and I had the same issue. It's definitely a Cygwin bug, but there's a workaround: try running:

```
 chgrp -R Users ~/.ssh
```

The longer explanation is that, for some reason, Cygwin's `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` generation are putting the user's default/main group as `None`. And you cannot change the permission of `None`, so the `chmod` for group has no effect.

I didn't try repairing the `passwd`/`group` files myself, but I did do a `chgrp -R Users ~/.ssh` (or, if you are on the Windows 8 pre-release, with the group name`HomeUsers`). After that, you can do the `chmod 0600` and it'll work as expected.

The `chgrp` to the `Users` group can be done in whichever other similar cases you find. It even works as expected since Cygwin puts users in the `Users` group as a *secondary* group (instead of *primary*, which would be the correct behavior).

Comment: I needed 

    chgrp -Rv Users ~/.ssh/*
    chmod -vR 600 ~/.ssh/*

Comment: @TomášFejfar comment above worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: @TomášFejfar that was very helpful, maybe it should find its way into install scripts or something

Comment: Yes, that would be lovely, but I usually can contribute only to github-based projects. Elsewhere it's too much hustle ;)

Comment: Note if you have Windows installed in another language `Users` is not going to work. Use `cat /etc/group` to check with what you should replace `Users`. In Dutch for example you would have to replace `Users` with `Gebruikers`.

Comment: Note that this also works for Mobaxterm.  The group in Mobaxterm is called UsersGrp.  Changing the group to Users allowed me to change file permissions and ssh worked.

Comment: This also works for those who use MobaXterm

Comment: It doesn't work anymore. The new solution is @luke-lee 's one.

Comment: @SnapShot MobaXterm has nothing to do with it, it's just a terminal emulator. It's like saying that you have registered yourself to the Facebook in Internet Explorer and than you found out, that you're registered to Facebook also in Chrome, Firefox and Opera. As a browser has nothing else to do with a website than displaying it, terminal emulator has nothing else to do with a shell than displaying it (and also sending user's input back to it).

Answer (score 29):

Starting from Cygwin 1.7.34 (2015-02-04) the method that changes the group to `Users` no longer works. Instead you need to use Cygwin's `setfacl` utility.

- Say, if you want to set file mode to `644 (rw-r--r--)` do this:

  ```
  setfacl -s u::rw-,g::r--,o:r-- foo.bar
  ```
- or use a longer format:

  ```
  setfacl -s user::rw-,group::r--,other::r-- foo.bar
  ```
- or copy its mode using `getfacl` from file `foo` to `bar`:

  ```
  getfacl foo | setfacl -f - bar
  ```

A complete manual is in the ["setfacl" section of the Cygwin user guide](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html#setfacl). I wonder why Cygwin has not yet changed `chmod` utility likewise.

Comment: solutions with group change to Users didn't work for me but only setfacl based one!

Comment: Luke, I think you missed a colon in your first code-block after the 'o'.

Comment: @SeldomNeedy Argh! You are right, corrected accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: @SeldomNeedy After some more checks I found both syntax works, but the original one (with one colon) is more accurate. The 2nd colon for 'u' and 'g' is for specifying UID and GID. For 'o' there is no such specifier so only one colon is needed.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a script that uses Luke Lee's suggestion but supports octal args like chmod.  It provides a framework that can be extended. although it currently only supports octal args needed to fix permission on key.pem and/or ~/.ssh directory and files.

```
#!/bin/bash

# convert chmod octal permission args to equivalent setfacl args
ARGS=() ; FILES=()
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  A=$1 ; shift
  case "$A" in
  600|0600) ARGS+=("u::rw-,g::---,o::---") ;;
  640|0640) ARGS+=("u::rw-,g::r--,o::---") ;;
  644|0644) ARGS+=("u::rw-,g::r--,o::r--") ;;
  700|0700) ARGS+=("u::rwx,g::---,o::---") ;;
  *) if [ -e "$A" ]; then FILES+=( "$A" ) ; else
    echo "unrecognized arg [$A]" 1>&2
    exit 1
  fi
  ;;
  esac
done
for F in "${FILES[@]}" ; do
  setfacl -s "${ARGS[@]}" "$F"
done
```

I used it like this to fix my .ssh directory and files:

```
chmodfacl 700 ~/.ssh
chmodfacl 600 ~/.ssh/*
chmodfacl 640 ~/.ssh/*.pub
```

Comment: Just got hit by this one in a cygwin update. Thanks for the script. `setfacl` on its own is horrible.

Comment: Where do I put the script?

Comment: the script can go anywhere in your cygwin path.  You might create a $HOME/bin directory and put it there, although you'll then need to add it to your path, e.g., in $HOME/.bashrc.

Answer (score 4):

```
chgrp -R Users ~/.ssh

chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/config

chmod 0700 ~/.ssh
```

Comment: These are the exact steps I needed, +1.

Answer (score 1):

If you have **git bash** installed run the same command (`chmod -c 600 key.pem`) with git bash and avoid **Cygwin**.

Comment: I am using git bash and have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be resolved by running the ssh-keygen command from the cygwin terminal.(Not the normal windows Command prompt). I have done this in my windows8 machine.

Comment: Can you please elaborate further? How can this fix the problem? What steps should the user take other than "run ssh-keygen from Cygwin"?

Comment: This just generates a key, but the OP has a key with bad permissions

Comment: Same experience here: chmod / ssh-keygen puts good permission under cygwin, but doesn't do it if I execute them from the windows cmd. (I don't know why though :-) )

Answer (score -2):

Run the Cygwin installer and update. The bug should be fixed.

Comment: Your post needs to be expanded. A good [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) includes specific instructions (not just links to them) and an explanation as to how or why the answer addresses the OPs question.  Please edit your post to adequately address both of these elements.