# How to change permissions under Mingw or Cygwin?

Tags: bash, permissions, cygwin, mingw, mobaxterm

My `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is 644 when it should be, I believe, 600. The host is Windows 10 and I have both git-bash 2.17.0 and MobaXterm 10.5-3582.

If I try to [change group](https://superuser.com/a/408221/209241), git-bash will fail with

```
$ chown :Users ~/.ssh/id_rsa*
chown: invalid group: ‘:Users’
```

MobaXterm will, however, change the group. Regardless, neither changes permissions, whether I use

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

[or](https://superuser.com/a/876913/209241)

```
setfacl -s u::rw-,g::---,o:--- ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The file permissions remain unchanged:

```
$ ll ~/.ssh/id_rsa
-rw-r--r--    1 MyUser UsersGrp      3243 Nov 30 18:24 /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_rsa
```

**Edit:**

```
$ getfacl /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_rsa
# file: /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_rsa
# owner: MyUser
# group: UsersGrp
user::rw-
group::r--
other:r--

$ ls -la ~|grep .ssh
drwxr-xr-x    1 MyUser UsersGrp         0 Nov 30 18:24 .ssh
```

("MyUser" is my own user, not literal)

Comment: Only root user can change group with semicolon  : Use. You should try . Period instead. But it seems that you aren't owner since  chmod falls

Comment: I mean that windows folder where id_rsa is stored . What are the actual permissions for your files and bash console?

Comment: what are the permision with getfacl of the file `.ssh/id_rsa` and the directory `.ssh/` ? To understand how permission works see https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html

Comment: @matzeri myuser/UsersGrp