# Using Cygwin in Windows 10, chmod 600 does not work as expected?

Tags: cygwin

`ssh` says:

```
Load key "C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/id_rsa": bad permissions
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/id_dsa
```

So I try to fix the permissions using `chmod 600` as is very standard on Linux systems:

```
me@DESKTOP-B7QCL2A /cygdrive/c/Users/me/.ssh
$ chmod 600 C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/id_rsa
```

But it does not work. `ssh` still reports bad permissions. Indeed, it seems that the `chmod 600` command did nothing:

```
me@DESKTOP-B7QCL2A /cygdrive/c/Users/me/.ssh
$ ls -l C:\\Users\\me/.ssh/id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 887 May 31 18:58 'C:\Users\me/.ssh/id_rsa'
```

I mean sometimes it works, if the file is in the home directory. I don't know why `.ssh` isn't in my home directory, it's odd, but let's not change the ssh configuration because I haven't touched it, just trying to add a private key file. Let's figure out how to fix permissions.

I tried all kinds of hacks suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/397288/using-cygwin-in-windows-8-chmod-600-does-not-work-as-expected), the `setfacl`, and the `chgrp`, none of it works.

Comment: mixing windows and posix path style is NOT a good idea. what is the output of : `A=$(cygpath -u C:\\Users\\me\\.ssh\\id_rsa) ; ls -l $A ; chmod 600 $A ; ls -l $A`

Comment: The main problem is likely `I don't know why .ssh isn't in my home directory, it's odd`. Are you sure that you are using the Cygwin ssh ?